# UISearchBar not removing navigation bar

Tags: ios, uikit

I am trying to create a simple search functionality where the search view is introduced from a main screen. I am using Interface Builder for this project, and this is what I have this view setup as: [image]

But when I click on the search bar the navigation bar disappears as expected, but the search bar doesnt shift up. [image]

How can I resolve this?

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"about to edit");
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Not sure if I am doing this right.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a UISearchBar or a UISearchDisplayController? The first one it´s just a search bar that you can place wherever you want on your view, the second one is the one that behaves the way you want, going up and covering the screen

Comment: I replaced it in case I used the wrong one with the UISearchDisplayController [here is a picture of the setup](http://i.imgur.com/m34OuP0.png)